# Android PopUpWindow Issue

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-menu

Here's my problem.  I have a PopupWindow that will be showed when a button was clicked.  I've added `setOutsideTouchable(true)` so when the user clicks outside the PopupWindow, the PopupWindow will be dismissed.

Now the thing is, when my popup is showing, and i clicked the button, what it does is it dismissed my popup and showed it again (which what it should do actually is just to dismiss the popup).  It dimissed my popup because clicking on the button counts as outside (`setOutsideTouchable(true)`), then it is shown again because my code on onclick told it so.

Is there anyway I can have my button included within the bounds of the PopupWindow so when clicked it would not dismiss it?

Thanks a lot. Appreciate help.
            }

Answer (score 0):

declarations

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private PopupWindow pw;
private View popupView
```

in the oncreate method

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null, false);
```

onclick method for the button

```
public void showPopup(View view) {
    pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    pw.setTouchable(true);
    pw.setFocusable(true);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    pw.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                pw.dismiss();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    pw.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
    pw.setContentView(popupView);
    pw.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);

}
```

This is the code which I use to implement the same.

**YOU CAN FIND AN [EXAMPLE CODE](http://androidsamplecodes4u.blogspot.in/2012/05/popup-menu-android-sample-code.html) HERE**

Comment: do you mind accepting the answer if it helped ? Otherwise let me know if the problem persist.